# Overflow bug bad chain length

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, block

Can someone recall how many blocks have been mined on the overflow bug chain until the new chain with the patch became the longer one?

Comment: You can estimate this by reading the corresponding forum posts.

Comment: Uh, you don't mean the 2010 arithmetic overflow inflation bug, do you?